# MInhas inserções não estão sendo salvas

Tags: python, postgresql

Instalei um cluster de postgres usando o pgpool em containers do docker, https://github.com/paunin/PostDock. Consigo conectar ao pgpool e fazer inserções e outros comandos normais do sql.

`psql monkey_db -h localhost -U monkey_user -p 5430`

Porém ao tentar conectar o banco usando o psycopg2 do python, faço inserções e aparentemente são salvas, mas saio do conexão e olho no psql e vejo que nada foi salvo. Ao voltar para o python vejo que nada foi salvo.

```
(docker) root@prisvo-asus:~# psql monkey_db -h localhost -U monkey_user -p 5430
monkey_db=# create table teste(num bigint);
CREATE TABLE
monkey_db=# insert into teste values(123);
INSERT 0 1
monkey_db=# select * from teste;
 num
----
123
(1 row)
monkey_db=# \q
(docker) root@prisvo-asus:~# ipython

In [1]: import psycopg2
In [2]: con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='monkey_db',user='monkey_user',password='monkey_pass', host='localhost',port='5430')
In [3]: cur = con.cursor()
In [4]: query = 'select * from teste;' 
In [5]: cur.execute(query);
In [6]: rows = cur.fetchall()
In [7]: for row in rows:
    ..:     print(row[0])
123
In [8]: query = 'insert into teste values(1111)';
In [9]: cur.execute(query);
In [10]: query = 'select * from teste;' 
In [11]: cur.execute(query);
In [12]: rows = cur.fetchall()
In [13]: for row in rows:
    ..:     print(row[0])
123
1111
In [14]: exit()
(docker) root@prisvo-asus:~# psql monkey_db -h localhost -U monkey_user -p 5430
monkey_db=# select * from teste;
 num
----
123
(1 row)
monkey_db=# \q
(docker) root@prisvo-asus:~# ipython
In [1]: import psycopg2
In [2]: con = psycopg2.connect(dbname='monkey_db',user='monkey_user',password='monkey_pass', host='localhost',port='5430')
In [3]: cur = con.cursor()
In [4]: query = 'select * from teste;' 
In [5]: cur.execute(query);
In [6]: rows = cur.fetchall()
In [7]: for row in rows:
    ..:     print(row[0])
123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa dar um [`commit`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.commit) pra gravar as alterações no banco.

```
cur.execute(query);
con.commit()
```